# Magento 2: Different static-content Files Per Locale?

Tags: magento2, locale, view, static-content

In Magento 2, a static content URL looks like this

```
http://magento-2-with-keys.dev/static/adminhtml/Magento/science/en_US/Pulsestorm_FrontendTutorial1/hello.js
```

This includes a `en_US` locale portion.  This strongly implies that either

1. Magento 2 allows you to create different static content files per locale
2. Magento 2 processes static content files for locale/gettext strings

Which of the above is true?  Or are both true?  Or neither?

How do I, as a Magento module developer, provide a static content files on a per locale basis?  Would this be different if I was a theme developer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Magento allows to provide static asset files per locale in the module or theme.
To provide such localized files, put them under `web/i18n/<locale>` folder inside the module or a theme. These files have priority above non-localized files.

Comment: how we can do the changes in phtml ? is it possible, because  in some case i need to add or remove some thing in phtml level in that case how to do it and also layout xml?

Comment: and also few of my custom variable or less files also need to be changed in that case how to do it

Comment: Same. Just phtml files should be located under `templates` and layouts under `layout` folders. For themes - this is first level of directories, for modules - it should be under `view/<area>`.

Comment: @BuskaMuza I am sorry but I tried different variations for the XML and PHTML but it didn't. Say my local is ar_EG and I want to insert a new CSS file in `default_head_blocks.xml`. The file is called from `theme\Magento_Theme\layout` ... what exactly should be the URL of my override?

Comment: `default_head_blocks.xml` should not know anything about locale. Paths to CSS should be referenced in XML as `<module>::css/<file>.css` (for modular file) or `css/<file>.css` (for theme file). If you put your localized CSS file in `<modue>/view/<area>/web/i18n/ar_EG/css/<file>.css` or in `<theme>/web/i18n/ar_EG/css/<file>.css`, it should be used automatically for a store with `ar_EG` chosen as locale.

Comment: @BuskaMuza Thanks for the solution. It works great.! I had followed the web/i18n/css method.  :)

Comment: Can this work in admin theme as well, if yes the how? because I tried but not working in admin theme. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of complete separate file for different language, you can extend the theme by overriding the default files. Either in extends.less or theme.less file. Below can be the structure to override.

yourtheme/web/i18n/yourlocale

For example :

app\design\frontend\Magento\luma_custom\web\i18n\ar_KW\css\source_theme.less