# How to add custom css file specific to language or store in magento2

Tags: magento2, theme, parent-child-theme

in my project i have 2 store one is for en other is ar_KW , i am creating new locale called ar_KW
when i run **magento setup:static-content:deploy ar_KW**

it will create a ar_KW folder in pub static folder which is same as en_US but i need to add new custom css file only for Arabic store that is ar_KW store but when i switch to en_US store that custom css should not load ,  in that case how to do it  ?

and also for specific language(less variable value need to change in that case how to do it? )

example :- i have two view one is en other one is Arabic that i ar when i switch store between store css class called direction value should  change from float left to right and visa-versa that is less variable value will change based on locale in that case how to do it in magento 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, see this answer - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/96080/18419
If you have localized images in specified folder (for example, in the theme), these images will be used instead of default ones.
Same should be possible for css or less files.

Comment: :-  i have my custom them called luma_custom so do i need to keep my less files and images for for Arabic that i luma_custom\web\i18n\ar_KW\css\source\_variables.less and luma_custom\web\i18n\ar_KW\media etc... i it correct ?

Comment: Right. It should work.