# Running php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy for different languages

Tags: magento2, css, deploy

Whenever I run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` it always generates files for `en_US`.

I would like it to generate files for `en_GB` instead.

How do I achieve this?

And is there a reference manual for these command line instructions? I tried looking on the official Magento 2 website, but couldnt find anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add custom css file specific to language or store in magento2](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95987/how-to-add-custom-css-file-specific-to-language-or-store-in-magento2)

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-dict

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB
```

or if you want for multiple languages:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB en_US ro_RO
```

Answer (score 3):

You can run below command for deploying Multi Language Website:

```
php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ar_MA ar_KW ar_DZ en_US
```

Also Run below Commands:

```
chmod -R 777 var pub/static
php70 bin/magento cache:clean
```