# Override M2 html in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout

I would like to override

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/estimation.html
```

so I've copied and edited it into:

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Checkout/web/template/estimation.html
```

Porto is my theme, but nothing is being overwritten, what's wrong?

I've already cleaned cache and magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: Hit this command : rm -rf var/di var/generation var/page_cache/ var/cache/ var/view_preprocessed/  pub/static/frontend pub/static/adminhtml    
And check in a private window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear the Magento cache folder also & set permissions

```
chmod -R 777 var pub/static pub/media generated
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
bin/magento cache:flush
chmod -R 777 var pub/static pub/media generated
```

If you are using multiple language please deploy to multiple langauges like ,

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB en_US ro_RO
```

ref : [Running php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy for different languages](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106380/running-php-bin-magento-setupstatic-contentdeploy-for-different-languages)

FYI : Check your file have permission, for your template file :   `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Checkout/web/template/estimation.html`