# Magento2: How to add css file in admin backend for RTL?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, css, head

I want to add custom css in backend that only work when user change the Arabic language from admin side.

How can I add css for backend on conditional basis?

Can any one help me on this which would be much appreciated for this.
Please help me on this.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95987/how-to-add-custom-css-file-specific-to-language-or-store-in-magento2 https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95118/magento-2-different-static-content-files-per-locale/96080#96080

Comment: its for frontend, not for admin, as i tried same for admin, but not working