# Magento 2 Direction RTL Issue

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0.2

Magento provides facility to specify different locale for each store view from the backend.

My question is, if i assign locale Persian, Urdu or anything (RTL Locale). Does that add **dir='RTL'** to HTML tag? Or How should i add **dir="RTL"** attribute to HTML tag for specific locale ? Do i need to customize magento for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the locale doesn't add dir attribute "yet", it's only change the lang attribute in html tag.
You can use check
[Magento 2: Different static-content Files Per Locale?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95118/magento-2-different-static-asset-files-per-locale/96080#96080)

I've start making an [RTL version for M2 default theme](https://github.com/talalus/magento2-theme-blank-rtl) but I don't think it's the best practice to create RTL version, maybe Magento need to add dir attribute in later releases.