# How can magento2 support .less or css for multi language locale?

Tags: magento2, css, language, less, locale

For CSS, I found that we can add `web/i18n/en_US/mymodule.css` for module

If I want to add some locale specific CSS for the core module, where should I put them in? `e.g. app/design/frontend/mypackage/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/web/i18n/en_US/catalog.css ?`

But if I want to add locale specific .less file, how can I do this?

Comment: Please check this answer [https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/96080/60973](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/96080/60973)

Comment: You must override a the less file you can’t with css

Answer (score 1):

You can add new CSS to the head of all your template pages.

**Create /Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml:**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/custom.less" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: how about for locale(multi-language) specific css?

Comment: If its same theme then you can use same XML if its different the add there too in XML

Answer (score 1):

[Simple ways to customize a theme's styles](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html) for magento2

> **Simplest way to extend parent styles**
>
> To extend the parent theme’s styles in your theme:
>
> ```
> In your theme directory, create a web/css/source sub-directory.
> Create a _extend.less file there. The path to it looks like following:
>
> <theme_dir>/
> │  ├── web/
> │  │   ├── css/
> │  │   │   ├── source/
> │  │   │      ├──_extend.less
> ```

for locale specific less, use this path

`<theme_dir>/web/i18n/locale/css/source/_extend.less`

Answer (score -1):

locale-specific not possible.

for locale assign you must need to assign store view.

For each store wise you can create new theme and assig it.

Hope it will clear your idea.

Comment: This isn't true. You can do locale specific styles and all other static content (images, js, css, fonts, ...) just by placing the files as @situee explained.